# google maps api v3 doesn't work while retrieving string data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm trying to place some markers on a map retrieving thier STRING address from a PHP document by an AJAX call (the PHP connects to a database and takes the data to reply to the AJAX call). Here's the JQuery/JS code:

```
function chiamaAJAX(idCli) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "scaricaContatti.php",
        data: "idCli="+idCli,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(msg){
            codeAddress(msg);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Chiamata fallita!!!");
        }
    });
}

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.165691,10.451526),
        zoom:6,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

function codeAddress(address) {
    alert('CODEADDRESS:' +address);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Now the problem is I can't make the geocode call work, the status returns always 'INVALID_REQUEST' (it means that the address is not in the right format) but if I place the full string of the address instead of the 'address' variable it works without problems...this makes me think that the datatype returning from the AJAX call is not good to be passed to geocode function, maybe it needs to be converted? How? Thanks a lot! Daniele

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the address variable in `String(address)` just to make sure it is getting passed as a string?

Comment: what's the response from `scaricaContatti.php`